# pass a swift var to a C api as void**

Tags: swift

I have a C api that looks as follows

```
struct foo_private_t;
typedef foo_private_t* foo_t;
void foo_func(void**x);
```

Where the API is intended to be used like this

```
foo_t x;
void foo_func((void**) &x);
```

Why the API takes a `void**` and not a `foo_t*` is beyond the scope of this question. The problem is when I try to call this API from swift. First I import the C header into swift via the bridging header. Then I try to invoke foo_func with a pointer to a swift object.

```
var x:foo_t?
foo_func(&x)
// error is cannot convert value of type 'foo_t?' (aka 'Optional<OpaquePointer>') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?'
```

That error is expected, I need a pointer to the pointer, so I tried.

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: x){ x_p in foo_func(x_p) } 
// error is cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>!'
```

This also seems reasonable as `x_p` is similar to `&x`, a single level of pointerness. The next attempt I would have expected to work.

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: x){ x_p in foo_func(&x_p) } 
// error is cannot pass immutable value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?' as inout argument
```

Searching around for this error reveals that if I was calling a swift function I should use the `inout` modifier to a parameter. But since I am calling a C api I am not sure that I can make such a modification. How can I pass a pointer that is a mutable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to pass the address of `x` to the C function
in a way that `foo_func()` can assign a new value to `x` (which
is what the C code

```
foo_t x;
void foo_func((void**) &x);
```

does) then it would be:

```
var x: foo_t?

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &x) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?.self, capacity: 1) {
        foo_func($0)
    }
}
```

Inside `withUnsafeMutablePointer()`, `$0` is a

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<foo_t?>
```

and this is *rebound* to a pointer of the expected type

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work.

```
var e = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(x)
foo_func(&e)
```

`x` is already a pointer, so it can be converted to a raw pointer. Then I need a pointer to that raw pointer, so I take the address of `e`. I guess I need the `e` variable because an implicit temporary value cannot be passed as an argument to an `inout` parameter. E.g.

```
foo_func(&UnsafeMutableRawPointer(x))
// error is cannot convert value of type 'foo_t?' (aka 'Optional<OpaquePointer>') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?'
```

Comment: Does foo_func only *read* the passed pointer or assign a new value to it? In the latter case, your solution will update `e`, but not `x`.